# Laravel get rows with specific day and month

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query in laravel:

```
$eventos = EventsData::join('tbl_users', 'tbl_users.id_user', '=', 'tbl_events.id_user')
            ->where('tbl_users.birth_date', '>=', date("m-d"))  //my error
            ->where('tbl_events.year', '>=', date("Y"))
            ->get();
```

I have a users table (`tbl_users`), with the date of the birthdays of each user. And an events table (tbl_events), which records the anniversary of each user. Thus creating a table that will get the next birthdays.

My `birth_date` is type "yyyy-mm-dd". The table events is the `year`. I want to get the next event on the current day and year.

ie I think the anniversary date must be greater than the current month and day, and the event with the top year to the current year

Answer (score 2):

Format the birth_date to mm-dd first before comparing it to date('m-d'), like so:

```
$eventos = EventsData::join('tbl_users', 'tbl_users.id_user', '=', 'tbl_events.id_user')
            ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT( tbl_users.birth_date, '%m-%d') >= ?", array(date('m-d')))
            ->where('tbl_events.year', '>=', date("Y"))
            ->get();
```

### Update

If your tbl_events ***doesn't have a full date attribute***, you could do this in 2 queries:

First, get the remaining events of this year:

```
$events_this_year = EventsData::join('tbl_users', 'tbl_users.id_user', '=', 'tbl_events.id_user')
                ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT( tbl_users.birth_date, '%m-%d') >= ?", array(date('m-d')))
                ->where('tbl_events.year', '=', date("Y")) // Get remaining events this year
                ->get();
```

Second, get the events for next years:

```
$events_following_year = EventsData::join('tbl_users', 'tbl_users.id_user', '=', 'tbl_events.id_user')
                    ->where('tbl_events.year', '>', date("Y")) // Get events for upcoming years
                    ->get();
```

Then merge them

```
$eventos = $events_this_year->merge($events_following_year);
```

Comment: if you have an anniversary date last month, the event does not appear in the year 2016 for example

Comment: I think I get what you want to achieve, can you tell me what other attributes do you have in tbl_events and give some example of what the value looks like?